# Why NaN is greater than any number in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Here is an example:

```
parseInt(50) > parseInt('a');
```

When executing this on a console, it will return `false`. My original code looks somewhat like this:

```
variableB = parseInt(jQuery('some-element').html());
if(parseInt(variableA) > variableB)
     // do something
else
     // do something else
```

Sometimes the `some-element` will not be filled and thus return `NaN`. When this happens, I do want the `else` block to be executed. I am actually getting what I expect, but I just want to make sure that it indeed is intended to work this way.

Comment: `if(parseInt(variableA) > variableB && !isNaN(variableB))`

Comment: You didn't test the reverse, did you? The *comparison*, whether `>`, `<` or `===` is `false`; `NaN` is neither greater-than, less-than or equal to any number. And, dammit, *next time I answer* instead of commenting... >.<

Comment: why not check for `variableB` to see if it is a `NaN` before continuing?

Comment: I hadn't tested the reverse David, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 8):

In IEEE 754 arithmethic, [the floating-point model used by JavaScript](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.23), `NaN` (or not-a-number) is, by definition, not less than, equal to, or greater than any other number.

Notice that this even applies to two `NaN`s: if `x = NaN` and `y = NaN`, the comparison `x === y` will return false.

Below I quote the portion of the [IEEE 754 Standard](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/mostRecentIssue.jsp?punumber=4610933) (Section 5.11) where this behavior is specified:

> Four mutually exclusive relations are possible: less than, equal,
>   greater than, and unordered. The last case arises when at least one
>   operand is `NaN`. Every `NaN` shall compare unordered with
>   everything, including itself.

Answer (score 6):

All comparisons involving `NaN` will always return false.
`NaN` is neither less than nor greater than any number.

Comment: Strictly speaking, though, that's not entirely true, is it; or does `!==`/`!=` not count as a 'comparison'? (I'm perhaps being pedantic, but I don't know if I'm missing a technicality in your statement or not.)

Comment: @DavidThomas The interpreter probably does the negation separately to the comparison. That is, it first checks if NaN == NaN or NaN === NaN (false) then negates (true). There's no non-equality operator, just an equality operator and a syntactic sugar for negating it. 8 years later is probably better than never.